Criminal Minds: Which episode has Garcia dressed in a suit?
I'm trying to chase down the season and episode which has Penelope Garcia wanting to be a little more hands on with the rest of the BAU... So she has a makeover which involves dolling herself up in a suit and wearing contact lenses... The scene I recall had her in the BAU jet standing there... I think Morgan was amazed (so was I for that matter)...
Could anyone point me in the right direction? I don't have the season DVDs on me, so I can't search for it... Google hasn't been very forthcoming either... It would have been a few seasons ago...

It's Compromising Positions, the 4th episode of Season 6. (Searching for wearing contacts in context with Garcia and Criminal Minds did it.) 

Garcia offers to help them out by taking over J.J.’s former duties.
  Hotch agrees to this nonsense on a trial basis, though he seems to
  secretly think it’s a terrible idea. 
...
In any case, Garcia ditches her glasses for contacts, tones down her
  flamboyant wardrobe, and tags along on the flight to Akron.
...
Overtaxed with trying to do too much at once, Garcia has a bit of
  meltdown. Morgan tosses her contact lenses in the trash, hands her
  back her glasses, and gives her a pep talk about Just Being Herself.
  The most adorable nonsexual couple on television then exchange a round
  of I-love-yous (the fierce bond between Morgan and Garcia is one of
  the few things that give me hope in this crazy, awful world), then
  Garcia changes into her usual outlandish garb and reverts back to her
  usual brilliant self to track down the unsub electronically.

Video clip showing Garcia's toned down glasses-less self, and Morgan making her take out the contacts and putting her glasses back on- OG (Original Garcia):




I had it narrowed down to S6E3+ due to it occurring right after S6E2 when AJ Cook left the show over a contractual dispute. I think you are spot on with your answer.
